# What state labor laws apply when you're working remotely from a different state?

Tags: united-states, labor

What state labor laws apply when you're working remotely from a different state? Let's say my company office's and team are located in California while I am working in the state of Texas. What labor law applies here? The labor laws of the state of California or the labor laws of the state of Texas? Did I divulge enough information here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen [here](https://www.natlawreview.com/article/multistate-compliance-employers-out-state-remote-employee), the laws of the employee's state and city are controlling, and not that of the employer. A person working for a North Dakota company in Seattle is owed at least Seattle minimum wage. This to "were the employee usually is working" so it does not suddenly switch when the employee takes a working vacation.